# Cannot access List from a class within an Array

Tags: c#, frameworks, game-engine

I am a beginner developer, and would very much appreciate if you can help me figure out the problem which is in my code. The code is particularly confusing, mainly because it derives from a framework. The comments should be able to somewhat allow us to understand.

```
// Create an IBindable List
public static List<IBindable> KyzerBindables = new List<IBindable>();

// Attach elements to a list, for better control over all of them
internal static void AttachBindablesToList(IReadOnlyList<Drawable> children)
{
    // For all the children classes located in Drawable list
    for (int i = 0; i < children.Count; i++) // children.Count returns 4
    {
        // For all of the SettingsSubsection which are present in the Drawable array
        for (int l = 0; l < (children[i] as SettingsSubsection).Children.Count; l++) // (children[i] as Subsection).Children.Count returns 0.
        {
            // Get a specific element
            var element = (children[i] as SettingsSubsection).Children[l];

            // if is a SettingsCheckbox
            if (element.GetType() == typeof(SettingsCheckbox))
                KyzerBindables.Add((element as SettingsCheckbox).Bindable);
        }
    }
}
// in another class
public class KyzerSection: SettingsSection
{
    public KyzerSection()
    {
        Children = new Drawable[]
        {
            new KyzerMiscellaneous(),
        };

        ...AttachElementsToList(Children);
    }
}

public class KyzerMiscellaneous: SettingsSubsection
{
    [BackgroundDependencyLoader] // Calls load, framework thing.
    private void load(OsuConfigManager config)
    {
        Children = new Drawable[]
        {
            new SettingsCheckbox
            {
                LabelText = "Something here",
                Bindable = new BindableBool(false),
            }
        };
    }
}
```

My problem is, the second for loop does not even initiate for the AttachBindablesToList. For whatever particular reason, it isn't recieving a count. I am uncertain of what I am doing wrong.

*Edit*:

If, in any way, the GitHub repository issue can clear some issues up, please feel free to navigate there and check the commit which contains these changes. https://github.com/Frontear/osuKyzer/issues/3

Comment: My apologies. I posted that accidentally.

Comment: There is no mystery here. If `children.Count` is 0 then there is no elements in the list. use a breakpoint to help better determine whats going on

Comment: I updated my question with slightly more information.

Comment: have you stepped through the code?

Comment: Yes, multiple times. If, in any way, the GitHub repository issue can clear some issues up, please feel free to navigate there and check the commit which contains these changes. https://github.com/Frontear/osuKyzer/issues/3

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `(children[i] as Subsection).Children.Count`?

Comment: I have updated my question to explain what the values are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reviewing your github repository, I believe the issue is caused at:

```
private void load(params here)
```

The above is not being called at the time of AttachBindablesToList. This results in an empty

```
(children[i] as SettingsSubsection).Children.Count
```

The best option is to create an empty instantiation method

```
public KyzerMiscellaneous() { /* create Drawable elements */ }
// then
[BackgroundDependancyLoader]
private void load(params here) { /* doSomething */ }
```

This will allow access to the children list since it has been initialized before, which therefore allows the second loop to correctly function, and pushes IBindables to your list.